Error in PySpark Structured Streaming: Reading from and Writing to Kafka Topics
Why am I getting an error when trying to read and write data to Kafka in my PySpark Structured Streaming application?
I am working on a PySpark application where I am trying to read messages from one Kafka topic, transform them, and write the processed messages to another Kafka topic. Here is the code:
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, lit

# Create SparkSession with required configurations
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("KafkaReadWrite") \
    .master("local[4]") \
    .config("spark.jars.packages", "org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.1.2,org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:2.6.0") \
    .getOrCreate()

# Read data from source Kafka topic
kafka_source_df = spark.readStream \
    .format("kafka") \
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092") \
    .option("subscribe", "data_stream") \
    .option("startingOffsets", "earliest") \
    .load()

# Convert binary data to string
kafka_stream_df = kafka_source_df.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING) as message")

# Transformation: Add a prefix "Processed: " to each message
processed_df = kafka_stream_df.withColumn("message", lit("Processed: ") + col("message"))

# Write the processed data back to another Kafka topic
kafka_write_stream = processed_df \
    .selectExpr("CAST(message AS STRING) AS value") \
    .writeStream \
    .format("kafka") \
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092") \
    .option("topic", "processed_data") \
    .option("checkpointLocation", "/tmp/kafka-checkpoint") \
    .outputMode("append") \
    .start()

# Await the termination of the write stream
kafka_write_stream.awaitTermination()


I am working on a PySpark application where I am trying to read messages from one Kafka topic, transform them, and write the processed messages to another Kafka topic.
enter image description here
